# WCF passing filestream

Tags: c#, wcf, filestream

As I know, when I put a file in filestream, the file does not exsist in memory.
But is it true that when I pass that filestream to my service from my client, the client put the file in the momory and only then send the byte[] to the service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 modes in WCF: [streamed vs buffered transfer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789010.aspx). You are looking for the streamed transfer mode to avoid loading the entire data in memory:

> Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) can send messages using either
>   buffered or streamed transfers. In the default buffered-transfer mode,
>   a message must be completely delivered before a receiver can read it.
>   In streaming transfer mode, the receiver can begin to process the
>   message before it is completely delivered. The streaming mode is
>   useful when the information that is passed is lengthy and can be
>   processed serially. Streaming mode is also useful when the message is
>   too large to be entirely buffered.
>
> To enable streaming, define the OperationContract appropriately and
>   enable streaming at the transport level.

Comment: Could you give an example here. Thanks